confusion between memory address and size
Sorry if the question appears silly, but I just really want to understand what actually are memory addresses.
When I asked this question on google, I found that some  people compared this with a post box number.
If this analogy is true, then how much is the size of data stored in 1 memory address?
Supposedly this is answered as some $x$ bits
Then consider the following (dealing with C++)
suppose I have a pointer to a int variable. If I output the pointer using cout statement, I will get some address. But, the size of the int variable 4 bytes. So potentially, the data should be stored over some memory addresses in the case ($x$ bits)<4 bytes.
If so, then what address is the pointer referring to?
even if $x$ bits> 4 bytes, I could create any structure with arbritary size of memory and then again make a pointer point to it. Even then a single address will be shown. Again, I ask what address it is referring to.
Anyways, if my perception of memory address is itself wrong, please provide the correct way to think about it.
EDIT: I just checked something on VScode.
struct node{  
    int data;
    node*ptr;  
};  


int main(){
    node n1,n2;  

    n1.data=1;  
    n1.ptr=&(n2);  
    cout<<n1.ptr<<endl;  
    cout<<&(n2.data);
}

both the last 2 operations yielded the same output.
So, it means the address of the structure and its components are same.
Does it mean memory address has no fixed capacity?
Kindly clear the confusion.

With respect to programming and programming languages (or computer architecture), ComputerScience @SE is the place for conceptual questions. For programming questions, there is StackOverflow.

The postbox analogy is good in some ways, but bad in others. A postbox number specifies where a letter is or is going to. Similarly a memory address specifies where data is/is going to. A postbox number is an id for a postbox and a memory address is an id for some physical circuitry* that stores some amount of data, usually 1 byte. (From here on I will use "byte" as an amount of data but also to refer to the physical circuit that is storing 1 byte of data.) However, a postbox can contain a bunch of letters where, as you pointed out, 1 byte is often not enough to store all of the data we are saying is at that address. While one could theoretically manage data differently, most programming languages will store any object in sequential bytes, and consider the address of the first byte in that sequence to be the address of the object. This means that the answer to your final question "Does it mean memory address has no fixed capacity?" is yes, sort of. A memory address can be the address of an object of any size, because the address simply identifies where the data for that object starts.
Now I will explain the behaviour of the code snippet you shared. You observed that the memory address of the structure is the same as the memory address of its components. That is &n2 == &(n2.data) You are correct. This is because C++ (and C) stores a class by simply storing its components in sequential bytes. If you were to output &(n2.ptr) you would see that it is equal to &n2 + sizeof(int) ( sizeof(int) will probably be 4 but it can vary depending on the compiler and the computer.)
Hopefully this cleared some things up for you!
*This isn't actually true, as there are several layers of abstraction managed by the OS. But an individual program more or less treats memory address as ids of real data storage.
